# How to add Listbox Dynamically to Wrap panel at runtime by using Drag and Drop in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my code, There is one listbox in right side, the listbox item is added to the another list box item inside the grid. The Grid is added dynamically by using the context menu. Till it is working fine. But now I want to move the whole list not list items, to the grid dynamically at runtime. Please anyone guide me to drag the whole list and placing the whole list to grid at runtime dynamically.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel
            x:Name="mainPanel"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Background="#F0F0F0"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Add Pabel" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
        </WrapPanel>

        <ListBox
            Name="memberCollection"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Width="150"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="memberCollection_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Name="Name" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
ObservableCollection<Member> member = new ObservableCollection<Member>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Karthick", ID = "20011", Address = "10, MainRoad, Chennai" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Suresh", ID = "20012", Address = "11, MainRoad, Madurai" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Arun", ID = "20013", Address = "12, MainRoad, Selam" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Gokul", ID = "20014", Address = "13, MainRoad, Coimbature" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Vishnu", ID = "20015", Address = "14, MainRoad, Goa" });

        memberCollection.ItemsSource = member;
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid panel = new Grid();
        panel.MinHeight = 150;
        panel.MinWidth = 150;
        panel.Height = 150;
        panel.Width = 150;
        panel.Margin = new Thickness(15,15,0,10);

        Grid gridDrop = new Grid()
        {
            Background = Brushes.White,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch                
        };

        gridDrop.Drop += grid_Drop;

        var panelTemplate = new DataTemplate();            
        var stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Vertical);            

        var name = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));            
        name.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Name"));
        var id = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
        id.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("ID"));
        var address = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
        address.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Address"));
        stackPanel.AppendChild(name);
        stackPanel.AppendChild(id);
        stackPanel.AppendChild(address);

        panelTemplate.VisualTree = stackPanel;            

        ListBox listBox = new ListBox()
        {
            AllowDrop = true,
            ItemTemplate = panelTemplate
        };         

        gridDrop.Children.Add(listBox);
        panel.Children.Add(gridDrop);
        mainPanel.Children.Add(panel);

        DataContext = new Member();
    }       

    private void memberCollection_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        object selectedMember = memberCollection.SelectedItem as Member;
        if (selectedMember != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(memberCollection, selectedMember, DragDropEffects.Move);                
        }
    }

    private void grid_Drop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox listContent = e.Source as ListBox;
        if (listContent != null)
            Console.WriteLine("", Grid.GetColumn(listContent), Grid.GetRow(listContent));

        DataObject item = (((DragEventArgs)e).Data) as DataObject;

        object Target = ((Grid)(sender)).DataContext;

        if (Target != null)
        {
            object listItem = item.GetData(Target.GetType());
            listContent.Items.Add(listItem);
        }                                        
    }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Hello. Take a look [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/draganddrop.html), and come back if you have any issue or question. We will gladly help you, but we cannot code for you ;)

Comment: @Bob, Please refer my updated code.

Comment: OK, good. Just a last question: do you want to move the whole right list  `memberCollection` into 1 tile? Or Do you want to automatically create a tile for each member of the right list? I don't really understand why a Tile should contain a list of `Member`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bob, I want to move the whole list into main panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to move the whole list and create a tile for each `Member`, then this is one way to go:

First of all, you should simplify your template and put it in the XAML.
XAML is much more efficient at handling any kind of template than the code behind

For your left mainPanel:

```
        <ItemsControl x:Name="mainPanel" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Background="#F0F0F0"  AllowDrop="True"  Drop="mainPanel_Drop">
                        <WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_Click" Header="Add Panel" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </WrapPanel.ContextMenu>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="White"  AllowDrop="True" Margin="15,15,0,10" Width="150" MinWidth="150" Height="150" MinHeight="150">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ID}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Address}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

And for your list (no much changes)

```
        <ListBox
        Name="memberCollection"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Width="150"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="memberCollection_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Name="memberName" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I added two ObservableCollection to manage the Data

```
    ObservableCollection<Member> member = new ObservableCollection<Member>();
    ObservableCollection<Member> mainPanelMembers = new ObservableCollection<Member>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Karthick", ID = "20011", Address = "10, MainRoad, Chennai" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Suresh", ID = "20012", Address = "11, MainRoad, Madurai" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Arun", ID = "20013", Address = "12, MainRoad, Selam" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Gokul", ID = "20014", Address = "13, MainRoad, Coimbature" });
        member.Add(new Member { Name = "Vishnu", ID = "20015", Address = "14, MainRoad, Goa" });

        memberCollection.DataContext = member;
        mainPanel.DataContext = mainPanelMembers;
    }
```

Then, the creation of a new Tile is much much more simplier:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mainPanelMembers.Add(new Member());
}
```

If you want to copy the whole list, then you have to give the whole ObservableCollection to the DragDrop manager:

```
    private void memberCollection_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        object collectionDataContext = memberCollection.DataContext;
        if (collectionDataContext != null)
        {
            DataObject dragData = new DataObject("DataContext", collectionDataContext);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(memberCollection, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
```

And when you drop it, you can simply add the Member one by one. You could also clear the collection before (but I didn't):

```
    private void mainPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        DataObject item = e.Data as DataObject;
        object listItem = item.GetData("DataContext") as IEnumerable<Member>;

        if (listItem != null)
        {
            foreach (Member member in (IEnumerable<Member>)listItem)
            {
                ((ObservableCollection<Member>)mainPanel.DataContext).Add(member);
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm not sure I understood very well what you wanted... I still don't know how you're using the Tile creation.
Let me know if you need to do something different.